# Trying to make page responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am trying to make the page linked responsive, specifically the menu bar. I've added the following CSS hoping to make the menu responsive but as soon as I drag the page down past about 1140 px width a gap appears between the menu bar and the slider above it. This gets progressively wider the narrower the page gets. Is there anyway to fix this ?

The font property is not having any effect, I've looked in the CSS file but cannot find the ID or class that controls font size in the menu ?

Page link: http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/?page_id=2160

Here's the CSS I've added:

```
#access {
background: url('http://dbtest.destinationballybunion.ie/wp-content/uploads/2014/05  
/new-menu-back1.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: contain;
}

#access {
position: absolute;
top: 4.35%;
left: 0%;
right: 0%;
z-index: 100;
}

#access a {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 11px;
}

#access a {
font-size: 4.5vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class .culture appears to have a margin top on it of 30px. If you remove that, it should fix it.

Comment: thanks Holloway, yeah I made .culture - which is the class applied to the main 'north kerry takes the stage' pic - relatively positioned and added top-margin 33px because I had the menu and the slider at the very top absolutely positioned. Added to this I used the top section of the main pic as the background for the menu. When positioned the menu background and the main pic should join seamlessly (see arms) but for some reason the top 33px (that has to be moved back down) is floating up out of sight and causing a misjoin with the menu. Sorry, couldn't sum it up shorter than that !

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the css stylesheet it seems like the id (#access a) is being overruled by this line of css:
NAV DIV UL LI.page_item.page-item-1145 A.

You could add !important to #acess a or you could alter the class NAV DIV UL LI.page_item.page-item-1145 A to control the font size within the menu bar.

Comment: thanks Robin I changed the font size for the class you mentioned and that worked. Cheers !

Comment: Just wondering how you tracked it to this class. When I use Firebug, I obviously can't highlight the menu text because it's still an active link ? Likewise with Inspect Element - is there a way to check menu or link for CSS this way ?

Comment: I used Chrome inspector for this. I've found firebug does not always say which class is overriding which.